# Chaining jQuery click triggers with multiple AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got 3 tiers of data:

- [ PHP Loaded ]
  "click"

  - [ Ajax Loaded ]
    "click"
  - [ Ajax Loaded ]

**I'm attempting to  trigger clicks using jQuery 1.91 on the AJAX links upon page load based on URL parameters.**

**The first load/click trigger works fine:**

```
var param1 = $.getURLParam("id");
var theShow = $('header#showhead' + param1 + ' a.theshow');
if (param1!=null) {
    $(theShow).trigger('click');
}
```

This loads AJAX content with an anchor to click and load tier 3 data via AJAX again.

I can't get the second trigger to fire.

```
var param1 = $.getURLParam("id");
var param2 = $.getURLParam("sid");
var theShow = $('header#showhead' + param1 + ' a.theshow');
var theSeason = $('header#seasonhead' + param2 + ' a.theseason');
if (param1!=null) {
    $(theShow).trigger('click', function() {
        if (param2!=null) {
            $(theSeason).trigger('click');
        }
    });
}
```

I've verified the two param variables **are** being seen correctly and are being used correcting in the selectors.

Basic HTML set up:

```
<section id="show1234">

    <header id="showhead1234">
        <a href="#" class="theshow">Title</a>
    </header>

   <!-- loaded by AJAX call on link above -->
   <section id="season000">
       <header id="seasonhead000">
           <a href="#" class="theseason">Title</a>
       </header>

       <!-- loaded by AJAX call on link above -->
       <section class="datastuff"></section>
   </section>

</section>
```

I believe the issue may be that the first ajax call isn't finished before the second trigger fires. I've tried using `setTimeout()` for the second trigger to no avail.

Any idea how I can trigger the second click after the first AJAX call is complete?

Can I create a local addition to the existing `complete()` function in the first AJAX request? (I don't really want to alter the AJAX at all if possible.)

I've seen other questions, I'm not looking to chain the AJAX calls themselves, just the click triggers.

Console is showing:

```
        console.log(param1);
        console.log(theShow);
        console.log(param2);
        console.log(theSeason);

404 //param1
[a.theshow, prevObject: init[1], context: document, selector: "header#showhead404 a.theshow"]
2425 //param2
[prevObject: init[1], context: document, selector: "header#seasonhead2425 a.theseason"]
```

So it appears as though the selector is never actually grabbed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. here's how I got it working....

```
        var param1 = $.getURLParam("id");
        var param2 = $.getURLParam("sid");
        var theShow = $('header#showhead' + param1 + ' a.theshow');

        if (param1) {
            $(theShow).trigger('click');
            $(document).one('ajaxComplete', function(){
                if (param2) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    var theSeason = $('#seasonhead' + param2 + ' a.theseason');
                    $(theSeason).trigger('click');
                    }, 300);
                }
            });
        }
```

**Placement** of the variable definition for `param2` makes a difference. It must be defined after the first ajax completes.

Binding the global `ajaxComplete()` function by using `$(document).one('ajaxComplete', function(){});` allows one ajax call to complete, then fires the internal statements. Since the page load will have the first call triggered, I only needed the first call watched.

Using `$(document).ajaxComplete()` caused the second call to fire twice (because it also completed). In addition, by binding to the `ajaxComplete()` function it ensure the second click trigger isn't fired until that first ajax call is finished, solving the timing issue.

The `setTimeout()` for the second click trigger is more about user experience than functionality. With the binded complete function, no timeout is really necessary. Without the timeout the events will fire in succession immediately. The timeout was added merely for a visual stair step.

Comment: This is not 100% reliable as it won't work if the user has a slow connection, and the ajax call takes longer than 1 second.

Comment: I agree... which is why I mention adding semaphores. And really.. this is a personal web app.. so there's only a handful of users. Not too concerned with everyone out there. :) The AJAX already has flags in it... so I just need to tweak a bit. Thank for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading `#seasonshead` via ajax, one problem could be that when you declare the variable `theSeason`, the element you are looking for, doesn't exist on the page yet:

```
var theSeason = $('header#seasonhead' + param2 + ' a.theseason');
```

You need to query the element after you appended it to the DOM, and after you have attached the click event listener to it.

Since none of these two things are shown on your code, I am assuming it is being handled by some other piece of code. so in addition to delaying the element query, I am going to suggest a timeout, to allow this hypothetical other code to run.

Another thing, is that you are triggering the second click in the first click's callback, and what you are looking for is the ajax callback. You can use `ajaxSuccess` (http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) to intercept all responses:

```
var param1 = $.getURLParam("id");
var param2 = $.getURLParam("sid");
var theShow = $('header#showhead' + param1 + ' a.theshow'); // this is already a jQuery object, no need to wrap in $() again later
var theSeason = 'header#seasonhead' + param2 + ' a.theseason'; // this is just a string
if (param1!=null) {
    $('body').on('ajaxSuccess', function() { // start watching requests
        if (param2!=null) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(theSeason).trigger('click');
            }, 0);
        }
        $('body').off('ajaxSuccess') // stop watching requests
    })
    theShow.trigger('click'); // trigger request
}
```

Be aware that if there are other ajax calls happening simultaneously, you will need to check the response to make sure you are handling the expected call.

Comment: Yup, my thoughts too. I tried a timeout. Doesn't seem to matter, even giving it an unusable time to wait. And yes, the second selector is loaded via AJAX after the first selector is clicked. I'd just really hate to create repetitive AJAX calls for this single implementation. But... maybe it's not possible any other way.. hmmm... What seems to happen is **any** function for the first click trigger is ignored. Doesn't matter what that function is. And as a separate function the second trigger won't fire because it's not present on DOM load... so you may be correct that it's merely blocked.

Comment: See my answer... I got it functioning so it's not blocked by the browser (at least not Chrome).

Comment: I can't believe none of us realised that before :) but chaining click events like you did, will just execute both functions immediately after each other. You need to wait for the ajax response. I added that to the answer.

Comment: Nope. That's non-functional, same as previous attempts. I think I need to add local semaphores to the AJAX calls, which is fine. I just didn't want to replicate or combine the calls unnecessarily. You've been a lot of help. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer, I used something different, but similar and got it all firing as expected. Thanks again for the assist.